# Output of functions defined as double and int

Tags: c, int, double, output

```
int i = 5;
int j = 3;
int k;
double a, b;

k = j / 2 * i / 10;
a = 0.1 * i * j / 2.0;
b = 0.1 * (j / i) + 3.0;
```

So by doing it by hand one would get k=0.75, a=0.75, and b=3.06. Yet when I solve it in Visual Studio I get 0, 0.75, and 3.00. I was hoping someone could shed light on this. I know int means only whole values can be output but why is b = 3.00 rather than 3.06 since b is a double?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the behavior of integer division in C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3602827/what-is-the-behavior-of-integer-division-in-c)

Answer (score 2):

All of your variables should be `double` because if they are `int` integer operation will occur and your result will not contain decimal places.

```
double i = 5;
double j = 3;
double k;
double a, b;

k = j / 2 * i / 10;
a = 0.1 * i * j / 2.0;
b = 0.1 * (j / i) + 3.0;
```

Answer (score 1):

In your code,

- `i` and `j` are of type `int`
- the integer constants used here are also of type `int`,

So, in case of

```
k = j / 2 * i / 10;
```

integer division / multiplication will take place and the *final* result will be **promoted** to type `double`. This is not what you want.

either

- use `double` for `i` and `j`
- use casting to enforce floating point operation.

Same for the `(j / i)` part in below case.

```
b = 0.1 * (j / i) + 3.0;
```

OTOH, in case of

```
a = 0.1 * i * j / 2.0;
```

gives correct output, as the constant `0.1` or `2.0` denotes a `double` type, and because of the usual arithmetic conversion of the operands, floating point division / multiplication is performed.

Answer (score 1):

Operators for basic data types returns the strongest type of its two operands.

`(j / i)` is a division of integral data types, because `i` and `j` are of type  `int`. Since `i` is initialized by `5` and `j` is initialized by `3` the result type of the division is `int` and the result value is `0`.

Either you adapt your code like this to get the reusult you expected:

```
b = 0.1 * ((double)j / i) + 3.0;
                 //  ^ this is now a floating point division
```

Or like this:

```
b = 0.1 * j / i + 3.0;
```

Note the type of the result of `0.1 * j` is of type `double` because `0.1` is of type `double`.

Answer (score 1):

since `j` and `i` are integers, `j/i` will result in integer `0`.

Integer division only gives the quotient and the remainder is discarded. E.g `10/4 equals to 2`